# Github does not ask for credentials

Tags: github

Github does not prompt for credentials

I have a problem with git remote. If i try

```
git push -u origin main
```

with github it gives me immediate error "remote: Write access to repository not granted.", not even trying to ask me for my credentials. (a few weeks ago it worked fine).

If i change remote to gitlab and try same it works as should (prompts for login credentials, and if they are correct then pulls).

So where it could be a problem, or something changed in github and http authentication requires something else?

Comment: do you use a token? if yes maybe it expired

Comment: I have few valid tokens. But problem is that it does not even try to ask for it

Comment: Do you use linux or windows? try using `git config --global --edit`, is your data correct? now if you use Windows, try and search for Manage Web Credentials in the toolbar, there you will find `Web Credentials` and `Windows Credentials`, delete what belongs to github (you should now be asked to add your credentials), in linux unset the credentials like this `git config --global --unset credential.helper` (works on windows too)

Comment: I am using mac. None of these commands helped. But interesting fact that i tried to push on windows and it worked. So problem is with macos, also tried xcode built in source control to make push and it too failed....

Comment: okei, so if you are using mac did you try using the token on the comand? `git push https://<your_access__token>@github.com/your_username/your_project_name.git`

Comment: This way worked. Also i found the problem. It was mac keychain app, i manually deleted all github records ant then i tried to pull it asked me for a credentials.

Comment: keychain, is like the Windows Credentials of windows i forgot to suggest it. Nice!